# Button in Sharepoint list - conditional visibility

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to create a button that only appears if the "Zapůjčeno" column is empty.

```
    {
  "elmType": "button",
  "txtContent": "Odeslat Žádost",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"7347b7be-696f-46c8-bae8-78c230a354b3\"}"
  },
"style": {
"background-color": "#03A9F4",
"color": "white",
"visibility": {
"operator": "?",
"operands": [
{
"operator": "!=",
"operands": [
"[$ID]",
"1"
]
},
"hidden",
"visible"
]
}
}
}
```

[Example with "ID" column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUpbr.png)

If I try it with the default column "ID" it works, but if I want to use my column "Zapůjčeno" it doesn't work.

Thank you for your advice, I am a novice in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the column Zapůjčeno internal name the same as the display name? You can see the internal name of that column in **list/library settings** an then click on the column name. The internal name of this column will in the URL.

I think you can then use something like this:

```
{
  "elmType": "button",
  "txtContent": "= if([$Zapůjčeno_Internal_Name]=='','Odeslat Žádost', '')",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "='{\"id\": \"' + if([$Zapůjčeno_Internal_Name]=='','7347b7be-696f-46c8-bae8-78c230a354b3','') + '\"}'"
  },
"style": {
"background-color": "#03A9F4",
"color": "white",
"visibility": {
"operator": "?",
"operands": [
{
"operator": "!=",
"operands": [
"[$ID]",
"1"
]
},
"hidden",
"visible"
]
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Rikking said, you need ro use the internal name in json.

My test column formating json for your reference:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
  
   "children":[
      {
         "elmType":"button",
         "style":{
            "background-color":"=if([$Zap_x016f_j_x010d_eno]=='','lightblue','')",
            "width":"80px",
            "height":"50px",
            "display":"=if([$Zap_x016f_j_x010d_eno]=='','','none')"
         },
         "txtContent":"=if([$Zap_x016f_j_x010d_eno]=='','Odeslat Žádost','')"
      }
   ]
}
```

Test result:

[image]
Zap_x016f_j_x010d_eno is the internal name of Zapůjčeno,the default language of my SharePoint Online is English.
[image]